# Help showing F is weakly lower semicontinuous

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, calculus-of-variations, semicontinuity

Given a compact subset $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{R}^N$, I wonder if $$F(u)=\int_\Omega f(u)\ dx =\int_\Omega (1-|u|^2)^2\ dx$$ is weakly lower semicontinuous (w.l.s.c) on $H^1(\Omega)$, meaning that if $\lbrace u_n\rbrace$ tends to $u$ weakly, then $F(u)\leq \liminf F(u_n)$. This is my reasoning:
Since $u_n$ weakly converges to $u$ un $H^1$, also converges weakly in $L^2$ and so, (up to a subsequence) one has $u_{\sigma (n)}\rightarrow u$ a.e. Now using this and continuity of $x\mapsto (1-|x|^2)^2$, $f( u_{\sigma (n)})\rightarrow f(u)$ and Fatou's lemma says
$$   F(u)=\int f(u)\ dx \leq  \liminf \int f(   u_{\sigma (n)} )\ dx= F(  u_{\sigma (n)})      $$
My question is how can I obtain the same inequality with the original sequence? And, is Rellich theorem useful here? Any answer is welcome! Thank you.

Comment: That is not a problem since you can start out by fixing a subsequence on which you converge to the $\liminf$ and then run the whole argument for that sequence. (Another comment is that weak convergence in $L^2$ of course doesn't imply pointwise convergence on a subsequence, but I guess it's fine for weak convergence in $H^1$.)

Comment: Thank you Christian.

Comment: So my reasoning is correct, isnt it?

Comment: I think it's fine after the adjustments I suggested, but I didn't really think about it carefully, so can't say anything for sure.

Comment: You are indeed using Rellich Theorem when stating that you have convergence a.e. of a subsequence (or at least I do not see any other way to prove this here).

Comment: See this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199046/weak-h1-convergence-implies-strong-l2-convergence-for-a-subsequence to notice that weak convergence in $H^1$ implies strong convergence in $L^2$. For the compact embedding of $H^1$ in $L^2$ to hold you need some regularity on $\Omega$, like $\Omega$ has a Lipschitz boundary.

Comment: Just for the sake of full rigor: a standard "sub-subsequence + uniqueness of the limit" argument is missing, to conclude that the strong $L^2$ limit obtained by Rellich compactness is indeed the weak limit we chose to start with.